# Mapping over array of objects return nothing but array is clearly filled, using React and context to pass state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

**Scenario::**
I have a parent component () that is using context API this is the Provider that passes the state to children components. Each of these children components has children ( a form to handle input ) when those forms are submitted  I then use props to pass the input all the back up the parent component () aka the Provider whose job is to call an external script to calculate data from what the user submits which is received as a promise. Once I get the data I setState with the updated data.

**My Problem::**
I have two arrays of objects that are added to the state after the user submits the form. One containing all the values of the input the user typed in. Two the results the external script returned based on however many values the user typed in. Now is when I want to render both arrays to the view once we get them. Array one renders fine, but array two renders nothing. When I log array two in the console the array is filled, but if I log the array[index] and give it a specific index I get undefined

1st User submits the form

```
<KeywordSearch submitForm={this.handleKeywordFormSubmit} name="Bracket" />
```

Form is passed up to the Parent Component the Provider it looks like this

```
handleKeywordFormSubmit = () => {
    let query = {
        options: {
            keyword: true
        },
        data: {
            keyword_bracket: this.state.values
        }
      }
    this.props.updateReport(query)  
}
```

Values array is structured like this

```
values: [
    {
        value: 'input1',
        label: 'input1'
    },
    {
        value: 'input2',
        label: 'input2'
    }
]
```

2nd the parent component takes the query and runs the external script, returns the result which is an object which is then pushed in an array. When we're done the new array is added to the Context.Provider state to be accessed by the children components Context.Consumer

```
handleReportUpdate = (query) => {

    if(query.options.keyword){
        console.log('Keyword');
        let keyword_bracket = []
        query.data.keyword_bracket.forEach(bracket => {
            tableBuilder.keywords(
                this.state.thisReport.client.data.organic_research,
                bracket
            )
            .then(keyword_summary => {
                keyword_bracket.push(keyword_summary)
            })
        })  
        console.log(keyword_bracket)
        let updatedReport =  {
            client: {
                data: {
                    ...this.state.thisReport.client.data,
                    keywordBrackets: keyword_bracket,
                },
                info: {
                   ...this.state.thisReport.client.info,
                   Keyword: query.data.keyword_bracket
             }
            },
            competitors: [...this.state.thisReport.competitors],
            name: this.state.thisReport.name,
            _id: this.state.thisReport._id
        }
        this.setState({
            thisReport: updatedReport
        })
    }
}
```

3rd the Rendering stage in the child component the Context.Consumer

```
<Grid item xs={12} style={{margin: '20px 0'}}>
      {
      context.thisReport.client.data.keywordBrackets.length !== 0 ?
          context.thisReport.client.data.keywordBrackets.map(bracket =>
              {
              return(
                  <div key={bracket.searchTerms.value}>{bracket.searchTerms.value}</div>
              )
              }
          )
      :
          (<div>Nothing Here</div>)
      }
</Grid>
<Grid item xs={12} style={{margin: '20px 0'}}>
    <KeywordSearch submitForm={this.handleCompetitorFormSubmit} 
    name='Competitor' />
</Grid>
<Grid item xs={12} style={{margin: '20px 0'}}>
    {
        context.thisReport.client.info.Keyword.length !== 0 ?
            context.thisReport.client.info.Keyword.map(bracket =>
                {
                return(
                  <div key={bracket.value}>{bracket.value}</div>
                )
                }
            )
     :
        undefined
     }
 </Grid>
```

Here's where it's confusing because by following the process above when its time to render the new state from Context the codes second rendering that maps the `context.thisReport.client.info.Keyword` are rendered perfectly fine on the screen. The first rendering `context.thisReport.client.data.keywordBrackets` returns nothing. As a test, you can see I have added a `<div>Nothing Here</div>`
if the condition returns false. At first, before the user goes through the process of submitting the form that is shown on the screen as expected. Once they submit the form it disappears and where `the return(
<div key={bracket.searchTerms.value}>{bracket.searchTerms.value}</div>)` the output should be shown its blank. I have log's in the console that says the state is there the react dev tools confirms it as well. One weird thing is if I try to access the array by index I get undefined `console.log(context.thisReport.client.data.keywordBrackets[0]) //undefined`

This is a lot to take in so thanks in advance for reading. If you have any solutions advice lmk!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the following?

```
handleReportUpdate = (query) => {
//create array of jobs
var getKeywordSummaries = [];

if(query.options.keyword){
    console.log('Keyword');
    let keyword_bracket = []
    query.data.keyword_bracket.forEach(bracket => {
        let getKeywordSummary = tableBuilder.keywords(
            this.state.thisReport.client.data.organic_research,
            bracket
        )
        .then(keyword_summary => {
            keyword_bracket.push(keyword_summary)
        })
        //push each job into the jobs array
        getKeywordSummaries.push(getKeywordSummary);
    });
    //wait until all jobs are done
    Promise.all(getKeywordSummaries).then(function(results) {
        console.log(keyword_bracket)
        let updatedReport =  {
            client: {
                data: {
                    ...this.state.thisReport.client.data,
                    keywordBrackets: keyword_bracket,
                },
                info: {
                   ...this.state.thisReport.client.info,
                   Keyword: query.data.keyword_bracket
             }
            },
            competitors: [...this.state.thisReport.competitors],
            name: this.state.thisReport.name,
            _id: this.state.thisReport._id
        }
        this.setState({
            thisReport: updatedReport
        });
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Okay, so I see what u want me to do pass all the promises into an array and use Promise.all to return all the results into an array. I logged the Array of promises and the value of the result of each promise before it is pushed into the Array. The Array of promises is `[Promise, Promise, Promise]`. Each promise being `Promise__proto__: Promise, [[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined`. But when I log the result of the call I get my expected result. The final result array returns `[undefined, undefined, ...]`. So why is it returning undefined

Comment: Found the solution thanks to you. You were right i needed to use Promise.all to complete all the call and then set the state